# Simulate a TM on another TM?

Tags: turing-machines

When it times to decide the decidability or undecidability, sometimes I see that we can simulate a Turing-Machine on another Turing-Machine. I heard it is related to Universal Turing-Machine. Can you explain what it means that we can simulates a TM on another Turing-Machine? For me, if I have a deterministic automata $M$, then I do understand that $M$ simulate on a input $w$, but the case for the question is so confusing to me.

Comment: It is exactly the same thing as the difference between an interpreter and a compiler. A Universal Turing Machine takes the description of some Turing machine and simulates the behavior of this machine in a way that is computationally equivalent to directly executing this same machine.